# Eid vs Schwur - der Unterschied

Tags: difference, synonym

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen diesen zwei Wörtern?

In der Erklärung des Wortes "Eid" wird "Schwur" benutzt und umgekehrt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Den Unterschied kann man an der Wendung "einen Eid schwören" gut ablesen:

Der **Schwur** ist die Handlung, die man ausführt, wenn man einen **Eid** leistet. Es kann dies das Formulieren und Aussprechen des Eides allein oder eine diese einbettende rituelle Handlung sein.

*Eid* bezeichnet den Vertrag an sich, den man eingeht, indem man eine bestimmte Sache verspricht oder als wahr bestätigt. *Schwur* bezeichnet den (oft rituellen) Vorgang, durch den dieser Vertrag zustande kommt.

Das kommt auch in den Ableitungen der beiden Begriffe zum Ausdruck. Ein Bund wird z.B. mit einem Schwur besiegelt, man *(be)schwört etwas*. [Früher wurde](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS22911), wie heute noch im Englischen ("to swear"), *Schwur* auch als Ausdruck für negative Verwünschungen und Flüche verwendet. Das Verb *schwören* hat nach wie vor ein breites Anwendungsspektrum, wobei immer die Bedeutung "feierlich sagen oder bekräftigen" im Zentrum steht:

> Er schwor vor Gericht, die Wahrheit zu sagen. Ich schwöre, dass ich
>   die Person XY noch nie gesehen habe.  Ich könnte schwören, dass jemand
>   im Haus war. Das nächste Mal lasse ich dich nicht so davonkommen, das
>   schwör ich dir.

Hingegen *leistet* man einen Eid oder *be*eidet etwas. Das Verb "eiden" allein existiert nicht.